# Mapping the "change kit" action to a trigger on Alesis DM10

Tags: equipment, electronic-drumset

Is there a way of mapping the "change kit" action to the triggers on the Alesis DM10? For example I would like to map "move 1 up/next" to the kick trigger so when I kick it, my drum preset goes from 5 to 6. I'd like to use this to be able to quickly and easily switch the kit (using the volume up/down or the dial is clunky, slow and not really practical).

I feel as if I read somewhere a few months ago that this is possible, but now I can't figure out how to do it so I'm starting to think it might not be possible and that I got it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got an [answer](http://www.alesisdrummer.com/index.php?topic=6999.0) on an unofficial forum:

> The DM10 manual (p24) reveals most trigger inputs can be assigned to
>   select next or previous kit/s.

This is from the manual:

1. Press EXT TRIG to enter the main Ext. Trig Menu page. The first page shown should be INP (F1).
2. Highlight the trigger name at the top of the screen using the CURSOR UP / DOWN buttons to highlight it and use the VALUE UP / DOWN buttons or VALUE DIAL to change it.
3. Use CURSOR UP / DOWN to move through the menu items and VALUE UP / DOWN buttons of the VALUE DIAL to change the *Function*.
4. Select *Next/Prev Kit* depending on what you want.
5. Save the drum kit.